# What are the submodules of tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, tensor-products

Given two modules $M,N$ over a ring $R$. What is the relationship between submodules of $M$ and $N$ and submodules of $M\otimes_RN$?

Is there some simple way to see what will remain a submodule and/or become a new submodule?

Comment: I'm no algebra expert, but I think this is a difficult question since the tensor product is a left adjoint, and hence right exact, but not left exact in general; $\mathrm{Tor}$ measures the obstruction to left exactness. At least for the case where $R$ is a field it will be true that tensor products of submodules will be submodules.

Comment: If $M$ is flat, then any submodule $S$ of $N$ gives rise to a submodule $M \otimes_R S$ of the tensor product, and similarly for $N$. Most submodules don't arise this way. If $S$ is also flat (which does not follow from assuming that $N$ is flat!), then we can also tensor with $S$ with a submodule of $M$. Most submodules don't arise this way either.

Comment: In general, none. For example, $M\otimes_R N$ might be $0$ with $M$ and $N$ being nonzero.

Comment: In fact, if the ring is not commutative $M\otimes_RN$ is not necessary a module, just an abelian group.